# Creating packet for sockets using pack

Tags: php, sockets, packet, pack

I want to create interface for remote console that requires usage of custom protocol that is documented [here](http://pl.scribd.com/doc/197246969/BF3-PC-Server-Remote-Administration-Protocol) on page 2. I created proper classes and packet that does meet protocol requirements. Problem is that it worked once (i thing it worked cause server returned packet) and now every request does not return anything. What I also should to mention is that server is allowed to ignore packet if it has wrong format. Have I created packet that is in conflict with protocol or it is something on related to this code?

Here is my word class:

```
class Word {
    public $word;

    public function __construct($word) {
        $this->word = $word;
    }

    public function pack() {
        return pack('Va*C', strlen($this->word), $this->word, 0);
    }

}
```

and here is my packet class:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'word.class.php';

class Packet {
    public $words = array();
    protected $size = 0;
    protected $is_request;
    protected $from_client;

    /**
     * Construct packet
     * 
     * @param   bool    $is_request 
     * @param   bool    $is_client
     * @param   string  $command
     */
    public function __construct($is_request, $from_client, $command) {
        $this->is_request = $is_request;
        $this->from_client = $from_client;

        $this->size +=4 ; // size of first paremeter (4 bytes integer)

        $command = trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $command)); // remove double spaces

        $this->size += strlen( str_ireplace(' ', '', $command) ) ; // size of words

        $this->words = explode(' ',$command);

        $this->size += count($this->words)*5; // add size of each word size + null byte (5 bytes for each word)

        $this->size += 4; // add size of packet size

        $this->size += 4; // size of words count
    }

    /**
     * Return words packet string
     * 
     * @return String
     */
    protected function getWords(){
        $result = '';
        foreach($this->words AS $word) {
            $word = new Word($word);
            $result.= $word->pack();
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Return packet for sending
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function pack() {
        return pack('C4VV', (int)$this->is_request, (int)$this->from_client, 0, 0, $this->size, count($this->words) ).$this->getWords();
    }

    public function getSize(){
        return $this->size;
    }

}
```

here is my socket_read:

```
$bytes_received = socket_read($socket, 16384);
echo $bytes_received." bytes received.\n";
var_dump( unpack('C4VVa*', $response) );
```

Ive tried also this and same results:

```
$bytes_received = socket_recvfrom($socket, $response, 16384, 0, $address, $service_port);
```

Of course i did tested code on php using root account.